# Regarding definitions of modular functions and modular forms

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, modular-function

I am self studying Analytic number theory from Apostol Dirichlet series and modular functions in number theory and I have a doubt regarding defintions of modular forms and modular functions. 
My question is - Both in  definitions of Modular functions and  entire Modular forms,  the function f is assumed to be meromorphic and analytic in upper half plane H  respectively . 
Is there any specific reason that functions are assumed to behave particular in upper half plane H not any other region of complex plane?
Why only upper   half plane  H is chosen not any other region?

Comment: they are only defined on $H$; moreover they usually have the real line as a natural boundary.

Comment: Consider a modular form $f$ on $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$, it satisfies $f(z) = f(z+1)$. Therefore, it has a Fourier expansion $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n e^{2\pi inz} \ (z \in \mathcal{H})$, where there are no terms of $n <0$ because of the growth conditions we have imposed in the definiton. Note $|e^{2\pi iz}|= e^{-2 \pi Im(z)}$. What would happen if $Im(z) < 0$?